# How to store big map j2me

Tags: bitmap, java-me

I need to create 3000x3000 bit map for coords of my robots. In theory I have a array MxM, M=3000, and if my robot see somthing, then in coords [5][5] example I put 1, if see nothing then 0.

1. When I tried create  `int[][] b = new int[3000][3000]`
   I have a problem - outofmemory.
2. I tried use RMS, but I can create 3000 rows, but only 50 cols
3. I think to use textfile, but I need a custom update, and working with textfile very hard in j2me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some approaches:

- Store your coordinates in a file, and
  load and update only those
  rows/columns of data into memory,
  that surround the robot (maybe a
  10x10 matrix). Buffering.
- Use a quadtree algorithm to store
  your coordinates. You may have to use
  the external file approach here too,
  but maybe you can think of something
  better.